# What does master mode do?

Tags: rocksmith-2014

I found no explanation of it, do notes played in master mode still count for your accuracy/completion? What are the exact effects and why are some notes more transparent than others?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ## MASTER MODE
>
> Quickly memorize songs, then show them off outside of Rocksmith.
>
> With Master Mode you can practice playing songs entirely from memory, all on your own. It’s the ultimate achievement in Rocksmith when you’re able to walk away and play your favorite song anywhere.
>
> ### What’s new in Rocksmith 2014 Edition:
>
> Master Mode is now gradual - playing well at the highest difficulty will result in the notes gradually fading out of view so that you’re eased into the experience. If you miss the faded notes, we’ll fade them back into view. It’s all about learning at your pace.

[Source](http://rocksmith.ubi.com/rocksmith/en-us/features/)